# How to shutdown a fs2.StreamApp programmatically?

Tags: scala, http4s, fs2

Extending `StreamApp` asks you to provide the `stream` def. It has a `requestShutdown` parameter.

`def stream(args: List[String], requestShutdown: F[Unit]): Stream[F, ExitCode]`

I provide the implementation for this and understand that `args` is passed in as command line arguments. I'm unsure however, what supplies the `requestShutdown` parameter and what I can do with it.

Specifically, I'd like to invoke a graceful shutdown on a `Stream[IO, ExitCode]` which is starting a Http4s server (which blocks forever).

It looks like a `Signal` is needed and must be set? The underlying stream that I'm trying to 'get at' looks like this:

```
for {
   scheduler <- Scheduler[IO](corePoolSize = 1)
   exitCode  <- BlazeBuilder[IO]
                    .bindHttp(port, "0.0.0.0")
                    .mountService(services(scheduler), "/")
                    .serve
    } yield exitCode
```

My `stream` def is [here](https://github.com/tobyweston/temperature-machine/blob/afaae67c1de98024de4cd9eb21f944c70d36b9d2/src/main/scala/bad/robot/temperature/server/Server.scala#L51) and `StreamAppSpec` from the fs2 project has something in the [`StreamAppSpec`](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/5fbc9977c6d2056b3fe415b7a75928114be4bc29/core/jvm/src/test/scala/fs2/StreamAppSpec.scala#L51) but I can't work out how I'd adapt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of the `requestShutdown` parameter that is supplied to the stream function as meaning *an action that, when executed, will request the  termination of the program.*

Executing it will consequently result in it ending the program.

Here is an example use:

```
  override def stream(args: List[String], requestShutdown: IO[Unit]): Stream[IO, ExitCode] =
    for {
      scheduler <- Scheduler[IO](corePoolSize = 1)
      exitStream = scheduler.sleep[IO](10 seconds)
       .evalMap(_ => requestShutdown)
       .map(_ => ExitCode.Success)
      serverStream = BlazeBuilder[IO]
        .bindHttp(port, "0.0.0.0")
        .mountService(services(scheduler), "/")
        .serve
      result <- Stream.emits(List(exitStream, serverStream)).joinUnbounded
    } yield result
```

In this scenario, we create two streams:

- The first will wait for 10 seconds before triggering the effect of
  terminating the app.
- The second will run the http4s server.

We then join these two streams so that they run concurrently meaning that the web server will run for 10 seconds before the other stream signals that the program should terminate.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions for hooking something up so tests for example can shutdown a server? Pre-`StreamApp` I was doing this manually with a countdown latch so I don't feel I'm getting much from moving to `StreamApp`...

Comment: @Toby I mean, the most basic way to force it would be to simply call `requestShutdown.unsafeRunSync()` to invoke the side effect at the appropriate moment.  It's not what I would suggest in production code but it's a simple way of testing it and seeing how it works.

Comment: @Toby In a more sophisticated approach, you could easily move the `exitStream` (or something similar) outside of the `StreamApp` and then join that stream with the `stream` from `StreamApp` so that you don't pollute your real server code with test shutdown logic.

Comment: I'll have a go and report back if I come up with anything interesting

Comment: I did something. It's not very interesting! https://github.com/tobyweston/temperature-machine/blob/6803e3bf4af7c7099d72d1671a3936cd7f84183e/src/test/scala/bad/robot/temperature/server/HttpServerTest.scala